# Using Aladin Lite app (not built for React) in React app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, astronomy

I would like to use the [Aladin Lite app](https://aladin.u-strasbg.fr/AladinLite/) on my React app.

When building a site without React, it is very simple to embed the app in a div by doing:

```
<!-- include Aladin Lite CSS file in the head section of your page -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://aladin.u-strasbg.fr/AladinLite/api/v2/latest/aladin.min.css" />

<!-- you can skip the following line if your page already integrates the jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<!-- insert this snippet where you want Aladin Lite viewer to appear and after the loading of jQuery -->
<div id="aladin-lite-div" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://aladin.u-strasbg.fr/AladinLite/api/v2/latest/aladin.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var aladin = A.aladin('#aladin-lite-div', {survey: "P/DSS2/color", fov:60});
</script>
```

Where you then have an object `aladin` to use in Javascript.

How would I go about using this app on my React page? It was not built for React and uses jquery.

I need to be able to access its props to change the field of view of the sky which in Javascript is done by:

```
aladin.setFov(1)
```

Would this be a good time for React portals?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this will help you: https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a React component that will render Aladin sky map (so there will be no Aladin anywhere else). Then, you can define and configure aladin inside `componentDidMount` (if you are using class components) or `React.useEffect` (if you are using hooks).

Index.html:

```
...
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://aladin.u-strasbg.fr/AladinLite/api/v2/latest/aladin.min.css" />

   <!-- you can skip the following line if your page already integrates the jQuery library -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

   <!-- insert this snippet where you want Aladin Lite viewer to appear and after the loading of jQuery -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://aladin.u-strasbg.fr/AladinLite/api/v2/latest/aladin.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
...
```

Aladin.jsx:

```
const Aladin = () => {

    React.useEffect(() => {
        let aladin = A.aladin('#aladin-lite-div', { survey: 'P/DSS2/color', fov:60 })
        aladin.setFov(1)
    }, [])

    return (
        <div id='aladin-lite-div' style={{ width: '400px', height: '400px' }} />
    )
}

export default Aladin
```

Then, everywhere you want to render Aladin sky map:

```
import Aladin from './Aladin'
...
<Aladin />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update to Michal's answer.

```
let aladin = window.A.aladin('#aladin-lite-div', { survey: 'P/DSS2/color', fov:60 })
```

The function `A.aladin` can't be called straightaway since it is an external JavaScript function.